# i am not able to get 50 results records by google search api

Tags: php, api

this is my code. which works fine for 10 records. but whe it will prompt error when i increase the number. please check it and let me know if you have any solutions.

```
    Thanks in advance,
    Ravi Sharma
    Softobiz Technologies 
<?php

    # JSON SEARCH RESULT

    // This example request includes an optional API key which you will need to
    // remove or replace with your own key.
    // Read more about why it's useful to have an API key.
    // The request also includes the userip parameter which provides the end
    // user's IP address. Doing so will help distinguish this legitimate
    // server-side traffic from traffic which doesn't come from an end-user.

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyC4o52-Q90FxNzMxY9FNryrONierFS3la8&cx=016278085151347603490%3Affuoqez1cew&q=ravi&num=20';
    // sendRequest
    // note how referer is set manually
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '202.164.43.51');
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // now, process the JSON string
    $array = json_decode($body);
    // now have some fun with the results...

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also from the docs:

```
Pagination
This API can return the first 100 search results, in chunks (pages) up to 10 search results long. You can specify the page of search results to return using the start and num query parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/

> Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to the new Custom Search API.

From: http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#tech8

> 8. Is there a limit on the number of results I can receive per query?
>
> Yes. **You can retrieve a maximum of 10 results per query**, and you cannot access information beyond the 1000th result for any given query.

What you're encountering is the single request result limit.